# Pytest: How to create standalone py.test script with plugins

Tags: pytest

I have a jira-pytest pluging.
I want to generate runtests.py script containing that plugin. How it can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the generate function does not currently bundle plugins as far as I know.  One could work around this by vendoring the plugin (or as it sounds like in this case the plugin is already shipped) and then enabling it in a conftest.py using the `pytest_plugins` variable.  If the plugin is on the PYTHONPATH (which it will be if it is in the same directory as the module/package being tested) then py.test will import and enable it.  See http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#requiring-loading-plugins-in-a-test-module-or-conftest-file in the documentation for details of this.